# Maven seems to be pulling in jars that have test scope

Tags: maven, maven-3, dependency-management

I have a war module that is being built and is including a few shrinkwrap jars that it's not supposed to. Namely:

```
WEB-INF/lib/shrinkwrap-api-1.0.0.jar
WEB-INF/lib/shrinkwrap-descriptors-api-base-2.0.0-alpha-2.jar
WEB-INF/lib/shrinkwrap-descriptors-spi-2.0.0-alpha-2.jar
WEB-INF/lib/shrinkwrap-resolver-api-1.0.0-beta-6.jar
WEB-INF/lib/shrinkwrap-spi-1.0.0.jar
```

These dependencies are all listed in our poms as test-scoped so they shouldn't be in our packaged war. More info below but my question is: why are these here. There's obviously something I'm missing - what is it/where can I look to find it?

When I show my effective pom, I see the following dependencies (omitting a bunch of stuff here):

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
...
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
    ...
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap</groupId>
        <artifactId>shrinkwrap-extension-descriptors</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-beta-6</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap</groupId>
        <artifactId>shrinkwrap-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap</groupId>
        <artifactId>shrinkwrap-spi</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap</groupId>
        <artifactId>shrinkwrap-impl-base</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver</groupId>
        <artifactId>shrinkwrap-resolver-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-beta-6</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver</groupId>
        <artifactId>shrinkwrap-resolver-api-maven</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-beta-6</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver</groupId>
        <artifactId>shrinkwrap-resolver-impl-maven</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-beta-6</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.descriptors</groupId>
        <artifactId>shrinkwrap-descriptors-api-base</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0-alpha-2</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.descriptors</groupId>
        <artifactId>shrinkwrap-descriptors-api-javaee</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0-alpha-2</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.descriptors</groupId>
        <artifactId>shrinkwrap-descriptors-api-jboss</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0-alpha-2</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.descriptors</groupId>
        <artifactId>shrinkwrap-descriptors-gen</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0-alpha-2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.descriptors</groupId>
        <artifactId>shrinkwrap-descriptors-impl-base</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0-alpha-2</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.descriptors</groupId>
        <artifactId>shrinkwrap-descriptors-impl-javaee</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0-alpha-2</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.descriptors</groupId>
        <artifactId>shrinkwrap-descriptors-impl-jboss</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0-alpha-2</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.descriptors</groupId>
        <artifactId>shrinkwrap-descriptors-spi</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0-alpha-2</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    ...
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver</groupId>
      <artifactId>shrinkwrap-resolver-api-maven</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0-beta-6</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver</groupId>
      <artifactId>shrinkwrap-resolver-impl-maven</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0-beta-6</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap</groupId>
      <artifactId>shrinkwrap-impl-base</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  ...
</project>
```

When I print the dependency tree, I get the output below (only showing nodes that have the jars in question in them. I do see that some of these jars are listed as "runtime" and "runtime (scope managed from test)" but I'm not sure if that is related or how they got switched/included as runtime since in most of the cases, the dependency those belong to are test-scope:

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:tree (default-cli) @ name_removed ---
...
[INFO] +- org.jboss.arquillian.extension:arquillian-seam2:jar:1.0.0.Alpha2:test
[INFO] |  \- org.jboss.shrinkwrap:shrinkwrap-extension-descriptors:jar:1.0.0-beta-6:test (version managed from 1.0.0-beta-5)
[INFO] +- org.jboss.arquillian.protocol:arquillian-protocol-servlet:jar:1.0.0.Final:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.container:arquillian-container-spi:jar:1.0.0.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.config:arquillian-config-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jboss.arquillian.config:arquillian-config-impl-base:jar:1.0.0.Final:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.container:arquillian-container-test-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:test
[INFO] |  \- org.jboss.shrinkwrap.descriptors:shrinkwrap-descriptors-spi:jar:2.0.0-alpha-2:runtime
[INFO] |     \- org.jboss.shrinkwrap.descriptors:shrinkwrap-descriptors-api-base:jar:2.0.0-alpha-2:runtime (version managed from 1.2.0-alpha-1)

[INFO] +- org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver:shrinkwrap-resolver-api-maven:jar:1.0.0-beta-6:test (scope not updated to runtime)
[INFO] +- org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver:shrinkwrap-resolver-impl-maven:jar:1.0.0-beta-6:test (scope not updated to runtime)
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver:shrinkwrap-resolver-api:jar:1.0.0-beta-6:test
[INFO] |  +- org.sonatype.aether:aether-api:jar:1.8:test
[INFO] |  +- org.sonatype.aether:aether-util:jar:1.8:test
[INFO] |  +- org.sonatype.aether:aether-connector-wagon:jar:1.8:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.sonatype.aether:aether-spi:jar:1.8:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.5.5:test
[INFO] |  |     +- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-classworlds:jar:2.2.2:test
[INFO] |  |     +- org.apache.xbean:xbean-reflect:jar:3.4:test
[INFO] |  |     |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging-api:jar:1.1:test
[INFO] |  |     \- com.google.collections:google-collections:jar:1.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-aether-provider:jar:3.0.1:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:3.0.1:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-model-builder:jar:3.0.1:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:3.0.1:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.sonatype.aether:aether-impl:jar:1.8:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-component-annotations:jar:1.5.5:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:2.0.4:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-settings-builder:jar:3.0.1:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:jar:1.14:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:3.0.1:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-sec-dispatcher:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  |     \- org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-cipher:jar:1.4:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-provider-api:jar:1.0-beta-7:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-file:jar:1.0-beta-7:test
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-http-lightweight:jar:1.0-beta-7:test
[INFO] |     \- org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-http-shared:jar:1.0-beta-7:test
[INFO] \- org.jboss.shrinkwrap:shrinkwrap-impl-base:jar:1.0.0:test (scope not updated to runtime)
[INFO]    \- org.jboss.shrinkwrap:shrinkwrap-spi:jar:1.0.0:runtime (scope managed from test)
[INFO]       \- org.jboss.shrinkwrap:shrinkwrap-api:jar:1.0.0:runtime
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like this was a problem with a BOM used by Arquillian:

https://issues.jboss.org/browse/ARQ-889

We've updated to the fix version and all is well.

Answer (score 3):

The 5 shrinkwrap jars you don't want are all dependencies of your test-scoped dependencies. But in the dependencyManagement section, `shrinkwrap-spi`, `shrinkwrap-descriptors-spi`, and `shrinkwrap-resolver-impl-maven` are listed as runtime scope.  My guess is that these runtime declarations override the test scope on the transitive dependencies.  And the runtime scope is inherited by dependencies of these dependencies.

So `shrinkwrap-spi` and `shrinkwrap-descriptors-spi` are included because their runtime declarations in dependencyManagement overrides the test-scope transitively inherited from your explicit test-scope dependencies.  Because these two dependencies are now runtime-scoped, they cause `shrinkwrap-api` and `shrinkwrap-descriptors-api-base` to become runtime as well.  I think `shrinkwrap-resolver-api` also gets runtime-scope transitively from `shrinkwrap-resolver-impl-maven` (it's runtime in dependencyManagement), which itself not included because of the explicit test-scope.

However, this is all mostly a guess, backed up by testing different scopes with some shrinkwrap dependencies in an empty project and seeing what got resolved.

If there isn't a reason you need `shrinkwrap-spi`, `shrinkwrap-descriptors-spi`, and `shrinkwrap-resolver-impl-maven` to be runtime-scoped in dependencyManagement, I'd remove the scope bits and try packaging again.  If you do need those to be runtime-scoped for some reason, you might have to set your five jars to explicit test scope in your dependencies block.

---

### **Edit:**

Here's a simple project to demonstrate:

**pom.xml**

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>my.group</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-artifact</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.6.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.6.RELEASE</version>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

(The `spring-beans` artifact depends on `spring-core`.)

Then I run `mvn clean package` and get the following output:

```
[INFO] Building war: /home/matts/test/target/my-artifact-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
[DEBUG] adding directory META-INF/
[DEBUG] adding entry META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
[DEBUG] adding directory WEB-INF/
[DEBUG] adding directory WEB-INF/classes/
[DEBUG] adding directory WEB-INF/lib/
[DEBUG] adding entry WEB-INF/classes/Test.class
[DEBUG] adding entry WEB-INF/lib/spring-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
[DEBUG] adding entry WEB-INF/lib/spring-asm-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
[DEBUG] adding entry WEB-INF/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
[DEBUG] adding entry WEB-INF/web.xml
```

But if I remove the `dependencyManagement` section from the POM, and create the war again, I get the following output:

```
[INFO] Building war: /home/matts/test/target/my-artifact-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
[DEBUG] adding directory META-INF/
[DEBUG] adding entry META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
[DEBUG] adding directory WEB-INF/
[DEBUG] adding directory WEB-INF/classes/
[DEBUG] adding entry WEB-INF/classes/Test.class
[DEBUG] adding entry WEB-INF/web.xml
```

Even though `spring-beans` was test scope, because I set `spring-core` to runtime scope in the `dependencyManagement` section, it was still included in the war.

Comment: +1 The `<scope>test</scope>` is missing for some of the dependencies which will of course make the transitive dependencies of them `runtime` as well - otherwise, the final product wouldn't work. So he has to make all of them `<scope>test</scope>`

Comment: I don't think that's true. You guys are looking at dependencies defined in the dependencyManagement node. All dependencies in the dependencies node are test scope.

Comment: But for dependencies included transitively (i.e., not explicitly declared in the `dependencies` section), the explicit scope in the `dependencyManagement` section overrides the scope inherited from the original dependency in the `dependencies` section.

Comment: I've added a simple example project to demonstrate what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Your dependency tree report shows runtime scope for some of those jars, so they are included into the war accordingly, i.e. to be available at runtime. Effective pom also shows default scope for some jars, hence the inclusion. All in all, you have to trace down the origin of your dependencies. Check dependencies and dependency management section in your poms, as well as all parent poms.

To make it easier to investigate, I'd create a test war project with some of those dependencies declared, so you can incrementally add and remove pieces of pom and see how does it affect the end result.

Comment: I think you were looking at the dependencyManagment section of the effective pom. The dependency section has all of the shrinkwrap dependencies at test scope.